# How do I play an mp3 from the file system on Xamarin Forms iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, mp3, avaudioengine

I'm writing an app which plays an mp3 file.

In Android this is straight forward:

1. Use `Xamarin.Essentials.FilePicker` to pick the mp3 filepath
2. Use **Android.Media.MediaPlayer** to play the mp3 filepath

I tried a similar approach for iOS:

1. Use `Xamarin.Essentials.FilePicker` to pick the mp3 filepath (either from icloud or on phone)
2. Use **AVAudioEngine** to play the mp3 filepath

This works in the simulator but throws an exception when trying to create an **AVAudioFile**. (LibVlcSharp also fails when trying to load the filepath).

```
NSError err;
AVAudioFile file = new AVAudioFile(new NSUrl(audioUri, false), out err);
//err is null after this call throws an exception
```

> Exception: "Could not initialize an instance of the type
> 'AVFoundation.AVAudioFile': the native 'initForReading:error:' method
> returned nil.\nIt is possible to ignore this condition by setting
> ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false."

(Setting `ThrowOnInitFailure = false` doesn't help as file is still null).

I suspect it's a permissions issue, so I tried using the **MPMediaPickerController**:

```
MPMediaPickerController mp = new MPMediaPickerController();
mp.AllowsPickingMultipleItems = false;
mp.ShowsCloudItems = true;
  UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(mp, true, null);
```

with `MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus` set to `Authorized` and the following set in info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>Select a music file</string>
```

This code does nothing whatsoever.

How can I get this or the file picker method to work?

**UPDATE**

I've managed to get the MediaPicker working. Will update on that soon.

My next problem is I get an `NSUrl` from the MediaPicker. If I pass this directly into the `AVAudioEngine`, it plays fine.

But if I save the `NSUrl` to a string for serialization purposes, and then try to recreate it with the following code, the same exception above occurs when trying to create `AVAudioFile`.

```
//url1 works fine
NSUrl url1 = mediaItemCollection.Items[0].AssetURL;
AVAudioFile file = new AVAudioFile(url1, out err);
        
//url2 throws the same exception above
string str = mediaItemCollection.Items[0].AssetURL.AbsoluteString;
NSUrl url2 = new NSUrl(str, false) 
AVAudioFile file = new AVAudioFile(url2, out err);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of saying “an exception”. It would be much more useful to tell us what the specific exception is

Comment: Exception description added above

Comment: Where is the code causing the exception?

Comment: Just added exception code

Answer (score 0):

You could call `NSUrl.StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource Method` and check the return value:

```
NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromString(audioUri);
var securityEnabled = url.StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource();
```

For more info, you could refer to [startAccessingSecurityScopedResource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417051-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso?language=objc)

============= Origin answer======

You may try using AVPlayer.

```
AVPlayerItem aVPlayerItem = new AVPlayerItem(new NSUrl(audioUri));
AVPlayer aVPlayer = new AVPlayer(aVPlayerItem);
aVPlayer.Play();
```

also add this in info.plist if you load from a http source

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Liqun. I've just tried your code but it throws an exception when creating the NSUrl: Could not initialize an instance of the type 'Foundation.NSUrl': the native 'initWithString:' method returned nil. Also at the end of the day, I still need the AVEngine because I need to be able to PitchShift the audio which AVPlayer can't do.

Comment: @jho You may try call ```NSUrl.StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource``` method. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I tried your new code, but `securityEnable == false` and same error occurred creating my `AVAudioFile`. Please see **Updates** to my post above.

Answer (score 0):

Finally achieved playback. I will document below the major obstacles I encountered and how I resolved them, in case anyone finds this useful.

**Displaying MPMediaPickerController**

The code above didn't work because I was trying to launch it from a popup window and thus needed to find the popup's corresponding `ViewController` instead of the `RootViewController` I was using above.

This post had the solution:
[How to find current UIViewController in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582728/how-to-find-current-uiviewcontroller-in-xamarin)

**Serializing a NSUrl**

In order to Serialize an `MPMediaItem` you can't simply use the Url string. You need to use:

`MPMediaItem.PersistentID` which is a `ulong`.

To recreate a `NSUrl` from the `ulong`, you need to:

1. Query the media library again for the `MPMediaItem` with that `PersistentID` using `MPMediaQuery` and `MPMediaPropertyPredicate`
2. Use the query resultant `MPMediaItem`'s `AssetURL` property

**Playing audio but no sound comes solution**

This one drove me crazy but turns out one of the phone's volume settings was preventing the sound emission.

This post and the following code solved the problem:
[Swift: Playing audio using AVPlayer - Audio is not playing, cannot hear audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53925971/swift-playing-audio-using-avplayer-audio-is-not-playing-cannot-hear-audio)

```
AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetCategory(AVAudioSession.CategoryPlayback);
AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetActive(true);
```

Thanks everyone for your help on this. It was much appreciated. Happy coding!

Comment: Glad you solved it! You could accept your answer, which may help others with similar question.

Comment: Can't accept my own post unfortunately, but thanks for your help anyway. It kept pushing me along until I found the answer :)